# How do I calculate easily radical of $124$?

Tags: radicals

Today I want to do some math exercises and suddenly I found that it asks me how much is radical of 124. However, I have made some researches and it gave me a very long number which is 11, and with huge numbers which is totally wrong.

How can I calculate in easy way? Or, is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: "and with huge numbers which is totally wrong": what ??

Comment: What course is that ? Without this info, can't answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It gave me 11,1355287257. Do you think is totally wrong answer, isn’t it?

Comment: It's perfectly correct. More decimals if you wish: $11.135528725660043844238942597837$

Comment: Oh, you **do** mean just the square root? The radical of an integer also exists.

Comment: @YvesDaoust correct!? How can you prove this claim?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think so, I’m not very good in translation.

Comment: @AlexA: I don't have to prove anything. You have to learn what irrational numbers are and how they are represented. And to answer my second question as well, which you disdained.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well it is important. Because I need to present my answer to someone correctly.

Comment: Ok, keep disdaining.

Comment: Yves Daoust asked "What course is this".  That is very important for him (or us) to answer the question.  I do not know why you say $11.1355287257$ is "totally wrong". $(11.1355287257)^2 = 124.00000000088986584049$ so that is very, very, very close.  But we need to know what *type* of answer you need and what *class* this is for.

Comment: @fleablood Ok, what I need is a short and simple answer, not very long like what it gave me on Internet. It also part from my math home work, because before I used to know and now I forgot completely how to calculate it, and I just need to be reminded only, that’s all I need.

Comment: It depends on what you are *asking*.  Are you asking how to calculate the value of $\sqrt{124}\approx 11.14$?  Or are you asking how to simplify $\sqrt{124}=2\sqrt{31}$.  And for the *fourth* time, what *CLASS* is the for.  Ar you taking basic arithmeic?  pre-algebra? high school algebra?  Calculus?  Differential Geometry? Graduate level Analysis? Post-doctoral research?  What????

Comment: @fleablood How to calculate and simplify this. I’m in grade 12, high school algebra.

Comment: Well, you calculate it by doing estimats and getting closer and closer to it.  $11^2 < 124 < 12^2$.  So try $11.5$.  $11^2 < 124 < 11.5^2$ so try $11.2$.  $11^2 < 124 < 11.2^2$ so so try $11.1$.  $11.1^2 < 124< 11.2^2$ so try $11.15$.  $11.1^2 < 124 < 11.15^2$ so try $11.13$. etc.  Give up when you get bored.

Comment: Newton's Square Root Approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I have made some researches and it gave me a very long number which is 11, and with huge numbers which is totally wrong.

That's totally *right*.  $11^2 =121 < 124 < 144 = 12^2$ so $11 < \sqrt{124} < 12$.  $(11.25)=126.5625 > 124$ so $11 < \sqrt{124} < 11.25$.  $11.1^2 = 123.21$ so $11.1 < \sqrt{124} < 11.25$ and so on.

Now $124$ is *not* a perfect square and so the square root will *not* be rational so we can estimate this forever and ever and never end and we'll only get an estimation.  And we live in the 21st century so if there's nothing to be learned by doing it by hand we can use a calculator and get $\sqrt{124} \approx 11.135528725660043844238942597837$.

But that assumes we *care* want value it is close to.  If you are doing a practical problem that requires us to buy enough paint to paint a square with the are of $124$ sq ft or whatever we can estimate to as much accuracy as we want.

But if we are theoretical mathematicians (yeah, go team!) we actually don't *care* in the least as to what *size* the square root of one-hundred-twenty-four is.  We care about writing an expression, $blah$, so that it $blah$ is an express that we know $blah^2 = 124$ (and $blah$ is positive). *AND* we want the expression to be must versatile so that $blah$ has *other* properties (such as it is twice the square root of something else or whatever we can see that as well.)

$\sqrt{124}$ is such an expression but we'd like to simplify it so it doesn't have any  square factors only the radical sign.  i.e  We'd like to express it as $m\sqrt{n}$ so that $n$ doesn't have any square in it.

So to do that we figure out the prime factorization of $124$.

$124 = 2*62 = 2*2*31$ and $31$ is prime so $124 = 2^2*31$.

So $\sqrt{124} = \sqrt{2^2*31} = \sqrt{2^2}*\sqrt{31} = 2\sqrt{31}$. (And we know $\sqrt{31}$ can't be simplified further because $31$ is not a perfect square and so $\sqrt{31}$ is not rational and can not be expressed as  a fraction between integers or as a decimal that terminates or has a periodal repitition.)

Another example:

What is $\sqrt{85584600}$?

$85584600= 2*42792300 = 2*2*21396150=2*2*2*10698075=$

$2^3*3*10698075=2^3*3*3*1188675=2^3*3^3*396225=2^3*3^4*132075=2^3*3^5*44025=2^3*3^6*14675=$

$2^3*3^6*5*2935= 2^3*3^6*5^2*587$ and $587$ is prime

So $\sqrt{42792300}= \sqrt{2^3*3^6*5^2*587}=\sqrt{(2^2*3^6*5^2)*(2*587)}=$

$\sqrt{(2*3^3*5)^2*(2*587)}=\sqrt{(2*3^3*5)^2}*\sqrt{2*587}=$

$2*3^3*5\sqrt{1174}= 270\sqrt{1174}$.

Comment: That’s the best answer

Answer (score 1):

We have $124=2^2\cdot 31$, hence the radical of $124$ is
$$
{\rm rad}(124)=2\cdot 31=62.
$$

Reference: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer).

Edit: Due to translation error, it seems that you mean
$$
\sqrt{124}=11.135528725660043844238942597837099041\cdots
$$

Comment: How can I be sure that what your answer is correct?

Comment: How can I be sure what your question is? In symbols, $\sqrt{124}=11.135528725660043844238942597837099041$.

Answer (score 1):

What counts as an easy way depends on how hard you want to work and how accurate an answer you need.

Clearly, since $11^2 = 121$ the answer will be a little bit larger than $11$.

You could experiment with $11.1$, $11.05$ and so on to get closer.

There's an approximation you learn in calculus that says
$$
\sqrt{x+h} \approx \sqrt{x} + \frac{h}{2\sqrt{x}}.
$$
when $h$ is small compared to $x$, so
$$
\sqrt{121 + 3} \approx 11 + 3/22.
$$

You can check:
$$
(11 + 3/22)^2 = 124.018595041...
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is Ethan Bolker solution in more details:

$f'(x)=\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$

$f(x+\Delta x)≈f(x)+f'(x).\Delta x$

We use function $f(x)=\sqrt x$ ; we have:

$x+\Delta x=124=121+3$   ⇒ $x=121$ and $\Delta x =3$

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}$

puting values of x and $\Delta x$ we get:

$\sqrt {124}=\sqrt{121}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt {121}}.3=11+\frac{3}{22}≈11.13636...$